# App to tell me where my money is going

Tags: gratis, finance

I would like to understand my finances better. I could just knock up an Excel sheet, but wonder if there is an app to help me.

I would prefer something easy to use, so that it doesn't become a chore to enter data.

I am thinking to divide outgoings into categories : food/utilities/charity/clothes/etc and enter each time I spend something.

I am not overly interested in having it access my bank account or credit card and do not want my data on someone else's server unless it is end-to-end encrypted, so that ***only*** I can access it. That having been said, I do spend a lot via PayPal/eBay & Amazon.

I always have my 'phone with my, so that would make it easier to enter data as I spend. OTOH, the screen real estate seems to make a Windows app preferable for analysis.

I am open to Windows/Android/self-hosted/encrypted web site, with a bonus if I can use both 'phone and laptop with the same shared data.

It would be nice if I could set up recurring payments.

I am looking for graphs & charts. Something where I can see easily where my money is going (maybe a pie chart) and spot trends, or even be informed of them by the app.

Sorry if that's a bit vague. I will examine any and all suggestions

Comment: I use [Quicken](https://www.quicken.com/) for this, but I also have it access my bank account transaction data (to reconcile my records with the credit card and account statements), and the last I was aware of, the mobile app required connecting your data to the Quicken cloud.

Comment: You might want to ask the bingleduck about "alternatives to quicken"

Comment: And a freebie that might meet your needs is [GnuCash](https://www.gnucash.org/).

Comment: May I throw in [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/finance_budget) again? With Jeff recommending GnuCash, that's available for Android as well (err, well, it has a "collector on-the-go" so you can't forget what you bought when AFK, and then can copy that to the desktop app if I understood correctly).

Comment: Since GuCash offers zero password protection, I won't be using it. Sure, I ***could*** set up a Veracrupt drive on my laptop, but why jump through that hoop? And what would I do on Android? The search continues